# How can i store tournament standings

Tags: django, django-models

i have a model class

```
class MobaTournament(Tournament):
    teams=models.ManyToMany(Team)
```

if a tournament have 20 teams. I want to sort of rank 1st team, 2nd team, 3rd team... How do you suggest I do this?
like;

```
1.XXX team
2.XXX team
3.XXX team
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store that in the [**`through=...`** table [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). Like:

```
class MobaTournament(Tournament):
    teams = models.ManyToMany(Team, through='MobaTeam')


class MobaTeam(models.Model):
    moba_tournament = models.ForeignKey(MobaTournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Basically if there exists a `MobaTeam` with a given `moba_tournament` and a given `team`, then that `team` thus is a member of the `teams` of that `moba_tournament` and vice versa.

We can thus store, and update the points of that team for that tournament accordingly. You can for example retrieve the teams with the corresponding points with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Team.objects.filter(
    mobateam__moba_tournament=some_tournament
).annotate(
    points=F('mobateam__points')
).order_by(
    '-points'
)
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot alter field moba.MobaTournament.teams into moba.MobaTournament.teams - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

Comment: @Enes: well if you already had that m2m in the previous migration, you will need to alter some migrations, since indeed, the `through=` model, can not easily be altered.

Comment: @Willeam Van Onsem thank you for your help. After a little effort, I managed to start it.
I have one last question, I have team  team1  team1score and team2 team2score fields in Match. How can i use "through" in Match class

Comment: @Enes: you can sort the teams by `score` like in the last queryset, except that you of course replace `mobateam` with `match` and `points` with `score` here.